# Is this a geometric series?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

A geometric series is, in general, defined by:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a\cdot r^{k}=a\cdot\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r},\quad\quad \quad\quad \quad\quad r\neq1
$$

If I have instead the following:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(f(n)\right)^{k}=\dfrac{1-\left(f(n)\right)^n}{1-\left(f(n)\right)},\text{?}\quad\quad \quad\quad \quad\quad f(n)\neq1;\;\forall\;n
$$
This also true, isn't it?

My question is related to the convergence of such series especially when $f(n)$
is a matrix? We know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}B^k$ converges if and only if $\mid \lambda_i\mid\lt1$ where $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue of $B$ [Geometric Matrix Series](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~math211/m211oh/m211oh96.pdf).

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}B^k=(I-B)^{-1}.$$

Now, what happen if $B$ depends on $n$?

Thanks.

Comment: If $n$ is a parameter, then it makes no difference. Just let $B=B(n)$. And you need to know that *all* eigenvalues of $B$ are less than $1$ in absolute value (or the norm $\|B\|<1$ for most norms).

Comment: Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}B_n^k=\text{?}$

Comment: Hmm ... I didn't see exactly what your question was. I see. But the same proof that works for scalars works for matrices, so long as we know $\|B_n^n\|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So if $\|B_n\|\le c<1$ for all $n$ and $\|B_n^n\|\le \|B_n\|^n\le c^n\to 0$, we're ok.